# Where to save files in Laravel 5 folder structure?

Tags: php, file, laravel, laravel-5

I have my Laravel project that will save files (txt or csv) after making some computations.

I'm looking after a best practice on where to save these files.
Maybe /resources/csv/...?

Second question how would it be the best way to reference this path from within classes?
Setting up the abs path in .env file? 
Is there a laravel method that will return the path to resources?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**/resources** are not the best place, as this folder is used for source files and is usually stored in source code repository (e.g. git).

Files that application generates usually end up somewhere in /storage folder - just create a **/storage/csv** folder there.

You should never reference those files directly from your classes. Laravel's filesystems are what you need - you can read more about them here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem. They make operations on the files (like **read, write, prepend, append, delete, move, get all files** and many more...) much simpler.

Start with defining a filesystems in your **config/filesystems.php**

```
'disks' => [
  'csv' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => storage_path().'/csv',
  ],
],
```

Now you can read/write your csv files via **Storage** facade from anywhere in your code like that:

```
Storage::disk('csv')->put('file.csv', $content);
$content = Storage::disk('csv')->get('file.csv');
```

Comment: My current need is to create the file then use it on the same execution. Not to have a "permanent" file reference. Anyway the solution you provide is awesome. Thanks

Comment: If  I have multiple subdirs in csv folder. What do you suggest to do to access them directly? Better defining more specific entries in config/filesystems.php ? or chaining up like Storage::disk('csv')."/mysubdir/../" (dunno yet how to write this correctly..)

Comment: Include the folder in the filename you pass to put/get, e.g. ->put('folder/file.csv', $content).

Answer (score 4):

You can save files in storage folder.

For example:

You can create a folder named csv in storage folder and get the path as follows:

```
storage_path().'/csv';
```

You can find the storage folder in

Laravel 4.2 : app>storage
Laravel 5+ : in root directory

Comment: Files in storage_path() are not meant to be accessed directly. Laravel's filesystems should be used for that - http://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem

Answer (score 1):

```
public function storePhotos($data, Request $request, $requirement)
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8'); //for spanish names
    $fileUploaded = $request->file('someVarFormName');
    $folder = 'docs/';

    $destinationFolder = date("Y-m");
    $destinationFolderInServer = $folder.$destinationFolder;//.'/';
    //$rules = array('file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc,docx,exel,exelx'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
    $validator = Validator::make(array('file' => $fileUploaded), $rules);

    if($validator->passes())
    {
        $originalFileName = $fileUploaded->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($originalFileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $fileExtension = strtolower(pathinfo($originalFileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        $linkFilenameTemp = strtolower(ToolText::createLink($fileName));

        $linkFilename = $linkFilenameTemp.'.'.$fileExtension;

        //get versioin number if filename exist
        $i = 1;
        while(file_exists($destinationFolderInServer.'/'.$linkFilename))
        {
            $linkFilename = $linkFilenameTemp.'('.$i.').'.$fileExtension;
            $i++;
        }


        //* quitar / si falla
        $upload_success = $fileUploaded->move($destinationFolderInServer, $linkFilename);
        $dbRegOfFile = NULL;

        if($requirement->have_file)
            $dbRegOfFile = new mdl_TramitesRequisitosFiles();
        else
            $dbRegOfFile = mdl_TramitesRequisitosFiles::where('requisito_id', $requirement->id)
            ->get();

        $dbRegOfFile->requisito_id = $data['requirementId'];
        $dbRegOfFile->publisher = $data['publisher'];
        $dbRegOfFile->publisher_entity = $data['publisher_entity'];
        $dbRegOfFile->nice_name = $fileName;
        $dbRegOfFile->link_file_name = $linkFilename;
        $dbRegOfFile->extension = $fileName;
        $dbRegOfFile->size = $fileUploaded->getClientSize();
        $dbRegOfFile->save();

    }
```